ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdtemp 'undefined\temp\puppeteer_dev_chrome_profile-XXXXXX' error in Laravel Puppeteer
I'm encountering an error while using spatie Browsershot in my project to generate a PDF from HTML content:
[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdtemp 'undefined\temp\puppeteer_dev_chrome_profile-XXXXXX'] { errno: -4058, code: 'ENOENT', syscall: 'mkdtemp', path: 'undefined\\temp\\puppeteer_dev_chrome_profile-XXXXXX' }

Here is the code where the error is triggered:
 $htmlContent = view('org.org')->render();
Browsershot::html($htmlContent)
    ->setNodeBinary('C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe')
    ->setNpmBinary('C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe')
    ->save('example.pdf');

Has anyone faced this issue before? How can I resolve it?
